# Get count of affected documents of Mongoose UpdateMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Suppose we have the code :

```
 await Employees.updateMany(
        {
          InsertDate: {
            $gte: _yesterday,  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
            $lte: _today  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
          }
        },
        { $set: { RegistrationDate: ... // some var that I generate } }
      );
```

How can we get the number of affected documents (count) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany), you can get the number of updated documents in the response's `nModified` field.

So you can access it like this:

```js
const response = await Employees.updateMany(
  {
    InsertDate: {
      $gte: _yesterday,  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
      $lte: _today  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
    }
  },
  { $set: { RegistrationDate: ... // some var that I generate } }
);

console.log("Number of updated documents: ", response.nModified);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB version >= 5.0 then use `modifiedCount` instead of `nModified`

For example

```
const response = await Employees.updateMany(
  {
    InsertDate: {
      $gte: _yesterday,  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
      $lte: _today  // date ojbect that is passed as a param
    }
  },
  { $set: { RegistrationDate: ... // some var that I generate } }
);

console.log("Number of updated documents: ", response.modifiedCount);
```